# AJAX setinterval() function duplicates my html?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I've created a table where one textbox is refreshed every 10 seconds with database query data, but everytime the function is executed, it kind of duplicates my existing html code. Here's a before and [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43d3J.png) picture

And my HTML:
EDIT: PHP too:

```html
<?php

include '../Login/db_login.php';
$page="bt1admin.php";
session_start();

$sql = "SELECT Contador FROM senhas2 WHERE ID=1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$nome = $row['Contador']
 
?>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Página de administração - A</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
   setInterval(function(){
   $('#refreshtb').load('bt1admin.php');
   }, 10000) 
  </script>
 </head>

 <body>
  <form action="" id="atender" method="POST">
 <table border="1">
 <tr>
  <td>Clientes em espera:</td>
  <td><label id="refreshtb"><?php echo  "$nome";?></label></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Selecionar posto de atendimento:</td>
  <td><select name="posto"><option value="n1" selected>1</option><option value="n2">2</option><option value="n3">3</option><option value="n4">4</option><option value="n5">5</option><option value="n6">6</option></select></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" form="atender" name="atender" value="Atender Cliente Seguinte"></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure you want this content refreshed into a `<label>` as shown? Sure seems like you are targeting wrong element

Comment: Originally it was an input type=text, but after trying various different solutions, <label> was the last one I've tried. I just want it to refresh normally without duplicating my table, doesn't really matter if it's a label/textbox/whatever, as I can remove the background easily or borders..

Comment: so what does `bt1admin.php` return? Seems like it is the whole table isn't it? If so reload the form element

Comment: It returns one row from a table, if I got it right. I'm still learning PHP, so pardon me

$sql = "SELECT Contador FROM senhas2 WHERE ID=1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$nome = $row['Contador']

Both the HTML and PHP are inside the same page "bt1admin.php"

Comment: But what is html structure returned? And explain in more detail overall objective of this refresh

Comment: It would be great if you could show us more of your code(PHP)

Comment: Edited the OP with the PHP. 

The principle of this project I'm working on is the following: An user clicks a button in a page, that button increments a database table field by +1 everytime it's clicked, this page should be refreshing the label/textbox every 10seconds to retrieve the last inserted value into that table field. If I refresh the page normally, it works flawlessly, but I can't do that in my project, I want it to refresh itself every 10 seconds, and from what I've read a setInterval() should be enough and I've no idea what I'm doing wrong. It works but it duplicates my table

Comment: SO empty the area before you add the new data to it

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your `bt1admin.php` file is returning the whole page instead of just the number. You could create separate file just for retrieving the data or do something like that:

```js
$(function() {
  var Main = {
    onDataSuccess: function(data) {
      if (data.success) {
        $('#refreshtb').text(data.numberOfAttendees);
        console.log('Last fetched:', data.now);
      }
    },
    onDataError: function() {
      console.log('error');
    },
    onDataAlways: function() {
      setTimeout(Main.fetchData, 10000);
    },
    fetchData: function() {
      $.getJSON('bt1admin.php?ajax')
        .done(Main.onDataSuccess)
        .fail(Main.onDataError)
        .always(Main.onDataAlways);
    }
  }

  Main.fetchData();
});
```

```html
<?php
  // this should be at the beginning of your PHP file
  // before anything is send to the browser
  /* ... */
  
  if (isset($_GET['ajax'])) {
    echo json_encode(array(
      'numberOfAttendees' => $nome,
      'now' => date('H:i:s'),
      'success' => true
    ));
    die;
  }
?>

  <!-- ... -->
  <form action="" id="atender" method="POST">
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>Clientes em espera:</td>
        <td><label id="refreshtb"><?php echo "$nome"; ?></label></td>
      </tr>
      <!-- ... -->
    </table>
  </form>
  <!-- ... -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input, but I can't really understand this code. I've placed it on my code, but the console shows and error output, every 10 seconds. So it's refreshing every 10, but not forwarding the data, I guess... I've also updated my original post with the PHP I have